# nginx gunicorn not running on port 80 for django project

Tags: django, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn

I am setting up a production server for django application. I am able to run it with the help of nginx and gunicorn. problem is that, when I am running it on port no 8000 or 8001, it's working fine. But when I am running it on port 80, It is not connecting. This is the command I am using ( from command line ) :

gunicorn abcd.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:80 ( not working )

gunicorn abcd.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 ( working )
because of this when i opens my website in browser, I have to give the port number e.g - abcd.com:8000

output of commands is :

```
1. netstat -tulpn | grep :80

   tcp    0    0.0.0.0:80    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    27506/nginx
```

nginx conf file is :

```
 server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name abcd.com;
    location / { 
       proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    }

location /static/ {
    alias /home/ubuntu/staticvirt/test_project/staticfiles/;
   }
}
```

Comment: you are doing correct. just run : gunicorn abcd.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:8000  and then type abcd.com into your url, your gunicorn will get bind with ngnix, gunicorn will run at port 8000 and ngnix will run at port 80.

Comment: please give that as an answer, @SubodhDeoli. It would help if you included the error (all you say is "not working").

Comment: that's not an answer ... it's a wrong command i am passing.
I have used @Yogesh answer, and it worked perfectly..